# How to programmatically control EOS 500D on linux?

Tags: canon, linux, automation

I would like to control my EOS 500D shoot by program which is running on the linux platform.

Is there any existing solution?

I've tried `gphoto2` but it does not seem to be very stable.

Comment: I've used gphoto2 in combination with my 550D and did not had any problems. Have you already updated your Camera to the latest firmware? Or check the gphoto2 version - is it the latest?

Comment: Could you please state what you mean in detail by "not very stable" ? If we have a scenario, we might be able to heko troubleshooting

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any other software than gphoto, which you mentioned. The only other solution I can think of is actually running canon's software with Wine. Don't know if it's worth the effort though. I never really tried.